# White space after textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, whitespace

I made a contact form with HTML and CSS. But I see some space after textarea element. I replaced it with an input element and the space gone, so it is related to textarea. What is the white space after textarea element and how to remove it?

[image]

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
input, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 70px;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: 10px center;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #E3FF00;
}
input[type=submit] {
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" /><br />
 <input type="email" placeholder="Your EMail Address" /><br />
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your Message Subject" required="required" /><br />
 <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Your Message" required="required"></textarea><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Send" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: it seems to appear because of the `display: block;` on the `<form>` element. changing it into: `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` fixes the issue for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `<br>` after every element in form css use this

```
form{    
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

and remove all `<br>` tags. Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The display flex with flex-direction of column solves it

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
input, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 70px;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: 10px center;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #E3FF00;
}
input[type=submit] {
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" />
 <input type="email" placeholder="Your EMail Address" />
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your Message Subject" required="required" />
 <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Your Message" required="required"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks jac wida, Because you did what "Shlok Jain" said (as you commented). I accept his/her answer and give you an upvote.